# send emails automatically at a particular time without running application

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, datatable

I need to automatically email the  contents of a datatable daily at a particular time(10AM and 8PM).  Without running the application  how will i achieve this.. Please help me..  How to autogenerate emails at a particular time

Comment: Well what've you tried so far?

Comment: Create a standalone app that connects to the database and email such content. Then create a task that launch the app everyday at 10Am and 8Pm.

Comment: You need to write a console application and which does the work of reading the database (preferably Linq to SQL) and sends out emails. Then use your Windows Scheduler (http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manas1/console-application-using-windows-scheduler/ ) to schedule the time and days when it has to run..

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql mail write a stored procedure that runs on a schedule using job services. Don't need c# and console app is a pain to build deploy and another app to manage.